# Como devolver numa JTextField o valor de uma comboBox base dados sql?

Tags: java, sql, combobox

No meu programa tenho um registo de clientes no qual contem duas comboBox. 
Uma é distritos e a outra é concelhos.

Tal como mostro na foto seguinte na comboDistritos tem vários distritos de Portugal. 
[image]

Ao selecionar Porto ou outro qualquer distrito vai mostrar na comboConcelho os concelhos correspondentes a esses distritos. Logo a comboConcelho depende da comboDistrito.

Por exemplo se escolher na comboDistrito "Porto" nos concelhos vai mostrar todos os concelhos de Porto tal como mostra na imagem seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao registar na base de dados um cliente, os campos distrito e concelho apareçe o ID correspondente a cada um deles.
Na foto seguinte mostro um exemplo de um cliente registado com distrito PORTO e concelho MAIA

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema está quando tento buscar este cliente, neste caso carregar o cliente nas JTextField correspondentes me devolve um erro. Na foto seguinte mostra a carregar todos os campos menos as combos.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro que me devolve é o seguinte:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Programa.M_Clientes$2.itemStateChanged(M_Clientes.java:444)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
    at Programa.M_Clientes.procura_contribuinte_e_coloca(M_Clientes.java:382)
    at Programa.M_Clientes$10.actionPerformed(M_Clientes.java:814)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`

O erro em foto tambem está aqui disponivel para quem preferir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira linha do erro "M_Clientes.java.444" ao clicar me direciona para este código: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da foto aqui:

```
comboModel1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    comboModel1 = carrega_combo_distrito();
    comboBoxDistrito = new JComboBox(comboModel1);
    comboBoxDistrito.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {

            comboModel2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            QueryResultDistritos temp = (QueryResultDistritos) comboBoxDistrito.getSelectedItem();
            comboModel2 = carrega_combo_concelho(temp.recordCode);
            comboBoxConcelhos.setModel(comboModel2);


        }
    });
```

Noutra linha de erro que diz "M_Clientes.java:382" se clicar me direciona para este código: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo da foto aqui:

```
void procura_contribuinte_e_coloca(){



        ClientesLigaBD cl = new ClientesLigaBD();
        if((cl.verifica_se_existe(txt_contribuinte.getText()))){

            Clientes lido = new Clientes();

            lido = cl.LerRegisto(txt_contribuinte.getText());

            txt_nome.setText(lido.getNome_cliente());
            txt_n_cliente.setText(String.valueOf(lido.getN_cliente()));
            txt_rua_av.setText(lido.getRua_av());
            txt_n_rua_av.setText(String.valueOf(lido.getN_rua_av()));
            txt_local.setText(lido.getLocal().trim());
            txt_email.setText(lido.getEmail());
            txt_telefone.setText(String.valueOf(lido.getTelefone()));
            txt_telemovel.setText(String.valueOf(lido.getTelemovel()));
            txt_cod_postal.setText(lido.getCod_postal());

            int idxD = getComboIndexD(comboBoxDistrito, lido.getDistrito());
            comboBoxDistrito.setSelectedIndex(idxD);

            int idxC = getComboIndexC(comboBoxConcelhos, lido.getConcelho());
            comboBoxConcelhos.setSelectedIndex(idxC);






            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente encontrado !");


        }else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não existe nenhum cliente com esse número contribuinte.");

        }
    }
```

Esse codigo carrega clientes nas JTextFields e as combos.

Alguém me sabe dizer qual é o problema ao carregar as combos?

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** pois swing precisa ser testado e executado para poder detectar o problema.

Comment: Problema é que isto é um projeto muito grande e não sei como o vou puder colocar aqui

Comment: Nao precisa colocar o projeto todo. Por isso se chama *exemplo MINIMO, completo e verificavel*, acesse o link e leia as instrucoes de como fazer um.

Comment: Ok vou tentar fazer o exemplo MINIMO

Comment: Ricardo, veja a pergunta que marquei como duplicata, o que voce quer na verdade é capturar o item selecionado e preencher o campo de texto a partir da mudanca de selecao, na pergunta linkada tem uma resposta minha que mostra como fazer isso.

Comment: Onde esta o link com a pergunta? Não encontro

Comment: Abaixo do titulo

Comment: Lamento mas essa resolução nao resolveu o problema

Comment: Entao forneça um **[mcve]** conforme eu ja comentei antes.

Comment: Mas o programa contem base dados como vou incluir isso aqui ?

Comment: Você ao menos teve o trabalho de clicar no link e ler até ao final? Na pagina da dicas de como criar um exemplo minimo, completo e verificável, basta segui-las.